# Uploading file to php through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

My form uses javascript alerts to communicate with the user as this is the preferred method in the company I work for (as opposed to constant redirects to and from the php handler file).

Because of this, I pass all my form data through some simple validation in jquery and send it on to the php handler via ajax. Here's a basic look at how I'm doing it...

```
var first_name = $(sender + ' #first_name');
var email = $(sender + ' #email');
var tel = $(sender + ' #telephone');
var comments = $(sender + ' #comments');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sendmail.php',
    data: { first_name: first_name.val(),
        email: email.val(),
        telephone: tel.val(),
        comments: comments.val(),
        success: function clearFields() {
            first_name.val('');
            email.val('');
            tel.val('');
            comments.val('');
            alert('Thank you. We will contact you as soon as possible.');
        }
    }
});
```

Having added an file input field to one such form as follows, I'm having trouble with the upload. While the email sends correctly, I don't think the ajax is sending any usable data for the upload on to the php file

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />

<script>

var upload = $("#upload");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sendmail.php',
    data: { first_name: first_name.val(),
        email: email.val(),
        telephone: tel.val(),
        upload: upload.val(),
        comments: comments.val(),
        success: function clearFields() {
            first_name.val('');
            email.val('');
            tel.val('');
            upload.val('');
            comments.val('');
            alert('Thank you. We will contact you as soon as possible.');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I've found a number of options for this, but all the ones I've looked at [such as this](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html) seem "hackish" to me.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: wht not to use jQuery Form? http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this through an IFrame

So you create a hidden iframe

```html
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="display: none;" src="#"></iframe>
<!-- note the src="#" -->
```

Then you create a form with some button and all fields you wish to have

```html
<form action="path/to/uploadscript.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
<!--target will tell the browser to run it in the iFrame with name="upload_target" -->
```

then in uploadscript.php you can use all form values as if they are regular $_POST values:

```php
<?php upload_file($_FILES['file'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['whatever']); ?>
```

This almost feels the same as using AJAX.

Comment: The page I linked in the question did involve doing the same thing, but it was a lot more involved which is why it seemed ver much like a hack... So where does this go to my php file that builds the email?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that I just pass `upload_target` to the sendmail.php file?

Comment: @Ortund Set the form action to your sendmail.php file, then it should be good to go. You can add any form you want, it behaves like a regular POST. I use this to upload an image, check if I support the filetype (if not I give JS alert ;) ) and otherwise insert it into the database. With all the fields. So I guess you can use it to send mail as well :)

Comment: Yeah this looks a lot like in your URL, except he creates some fancy 'upload starting' text and a progressbar etc. It can be as simple as this, make sure to let your users know in some way that a file is being uploaded in the background and they have to wait for it to finish etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax does not support `file` upload operation. But there are many plugins which make use of iframes to upload files asynchronously. You can read more about this technique [here](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html).

Few jQuery plugins which supports form uploads are
1. [jQuery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)
2. [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

There are a lot of question answers regarding this in many Q&A sites, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Another solution using html 5 is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) which uses FormData.